# Android Geolocation Null in Titanium

Tags: android, geolocation, titanium

I can't get geolocations in the emulator or on a physical phone.

I'm using Titanium SDK **1.6.2**, ADK **2.2**.

I've followed the [approaches used here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/106441/geolocation-cant-get-coords-on-android-emulator) to no avail.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Error:

Says that `e.coords` is null when doing this assignment. `f_lng = e.coords.longitude;`

Code:

```
function get_geolocation() {

    try {

        Ti.Geolocation.preferredProvider = 'gps';
        Titanium.Geolocation.accuracy = Titanium.Geolocation.ACCURACY_BEST;
        Titanium.Geolocation.distanceFilter = 10;

        if( Titanium.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled === false ) {
            throw('Your device has GPS turned off. Please turn it on.');
        }

        var f_lat, f_lng;

        Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {

            if( ! e.success || e.error ) {
                alert("Unable to get your location.");
            }

            f_lng = e.coords.longitude;
            f_lat = e.coords.latitude;
        });

        return {
            's_status': 'success',
            'f_lat': f_lat,
            'f_lng': f_lng
        };

    } catch( s_error ) {

        return {
            's_status': 'error',
            's_message': s_error
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it return the `'s_status'` as `'success'` or `'error'`?

Comment: It doesn't get that far. It chokes every time at the `f_lng = e.coords.longitude` with the error that `e.coords` is `null`.

Comment: I'm trying to compare it to this working 1.5.1 android code. http://pastie.org/1396894 but the only difference I see really so far that would make any change is the `return;` in the `e.error` check at line 99?

Comment: i edited my answers, the code works, just tested it... Looks like `Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition` doesn't work too well on Android

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Ti.App.GeoApp = {};

Ti.Geolocation.preferredProvider = Titanium.Geolocation.PROVIDER_GPS;
Ti.Geolocation.purpose = "testing";
Titanium.Geolocation.accuracy = Titanium.Geolocation.ACCURACY_BEST;
Titanium.Geolocation.distanceFilter = 10;

if( Titanium.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled === false ) {
    Ti.API.debug('Your device has GPS turned off. Please turn it on.');
}


function updatePosition(e) {

    if( ! e.success || e.error ) {
        alert("Unable to get your location.");
        Ti.API.debug(JSON.stringify(e));
        Ti.API.debug(e);
        return;
    }

    Ti.App.fireEvent("app:got.location", {
        "coords" : e.coords
    });
};

Ti.App.addEventListener("app:got.location", function(d) {
    Ti.App.GeoApp.f_lng = d.longitude;
    Ti.App.GeoApp.f_lat = d.latitude;
    Ti.API.debug(JSON.stringify(d));
    Ti.Geolocation.removeEventListener('location', updatePosition);

    alert(JSON.stringify(d));

});

var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup();


//
// create base UI tab and root window
//
var window = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    barColor:'#003333',
});
var tab1 = Titanium.UI.createTab({
    icon:'KS_nav_views.png',
    title:'Tab 1',
    window:window
});

tabGroup.open();

Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition( updatePosition );    
Titanium.Geolocation.addEventListener( 'location', updatePosition );
```

see more details here http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/5384374513/titanium-appcelerator-quickie-get-location-android

Comment: I'v seen you use this magical `"app:something"` syntax before. For the non experts like myself can you give a quick explanation of how those work or at least where I can find documentation on them?

Comment: it is really just firing and an event. I use the `app` prefix so i know that it is a generalized event. if I was firing a `login` event, i might name it `login:success`, `login:failure` ...

Comment: Okay that makes a lot of sense, don't know how I event missed that. Thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks for the good code. I've made these changes, however, it still doesn't resolve my problem which is that the coordinates are still returning blank. Are there some kind of permissions that I need approved or possibly a bug in one the SDKs?

Answer (score 1):

Piggy-backing off of Aaron's answer, here is what worked for me on IPhone Simulator, IPhone, and Android phone (not Android simulator). Keep in mind that I use [redux](https://github.com/dawsontoth/Appcelerator-Titanium-Redux) so the code will be a little different.

```
var path = Ti.Platform.name == 'android' ? Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory : "../../";

var map = {

    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    latitude: 0,
    longitude: 0,
    latitudeDelta: 0.1,
    longitudeDelta: 0.1,
    display: "map",

    init: function (annotations, latitude, longitude, top, bottom, delta) {

        if (top)
            map.top = top;
        if (bottom)
            map.bottom = bottom;
        if (delta) {
            map.latitudeDelta = delta;
            map.longitudeDelta = delta;
        }

        map.createMap(annotations, latitude, longitude);
        map.createOptions();
        map.getLocation();

    },

    createMap: function (annotations, latitude, longitude) {

        map.mapView = Ti.Map.createView({
            mapType: Ti.Map.STANDARD_TYPE, animate: true, regionFit: false, userLocation: true,
            region: { latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, latitudeDelta: map.latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta: map.longitudeDelta },
            annotations: annotations, bottom: map.bottom, top: map.top, borderWidth: 1
        });
        if (!isAndroid) {
            map.mapView.addAnnotation(annotations[0]);
        }
        map.mapView.selectAnnotation(annotations[0]);
        win.add(map.mapView);

    },

    createOptions: function () {

        //map/satellite displays.
        var mapDisplay = new ImageView({ image: path + 'images/map/satellite-view.png', width: 70, height: 49, zIndex: 2, top: map.top + 5, right: 5 });
        mapDisplay.addEventListener('click', function () {
            if (map.display == "map") {
                map.mapView.setMapType(Titanium.Map.SATELLITE_TYPE);
                mapDisplay.image = path + "images/map/map-view.png";
                map.display = "satellite";
            }
            else {
                map.mapView.setMapType(Titanium.Map.STANDARD_TYPE);
                mapDisplay.image = path + "images/map/satellite-view.png";
                map.display = "map";
            }
        });
        win.add(mapDisplay);

        //crosshairs.
        if(Ti.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled) {
            var centerDisplay = new ImageView({ image: path + 'images/map/crosshairs.png', width: 49, height: 49, zIndex: 2, top: map.top + 5, right: 80 });
            centerDisplay.addEventListener('click', function () {
                if(map.latitude != 0 && map.longitude != 0) {
                    info("setting user location to " + map.latitude + " / " + map.longitude);
                    //center map.
                    var userLocation = {
                        latitude: map.latitude,
                        longitude: map.longitude,
                        latitudeDelta: map.latitudeDelta,
                        longitudeDelta: map.longitudeDelta,
                        animate: true
                    };
                    map.mapView.setLocation(userLocation);
                }
            });
            win.add(centerDisplay);
        }

    },

    createAnnotation: function (title, subtitle, latitude, longitude, isLocation, addToMap) {

        var mapAnnotation = Ti.Map.createAnnotation({
            latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude,
            title: title,
            subtitle: subtitle,
            animate: true
        });
        if (isAndroid) {
            mapAnnotation.pinImage = path + (isLocation ? "images/map/blue-pin.png" : "images/map/purple-pin.png");
        }
        else {
            mapAnnotation.pincolor = isLocation ? Ti.Map.ANNOTATION_PURPLE : Ti.Map.ANNOTATION_RED;
        }

        if (addToMap)
            map.mapView.addAnnotation(mapAnnotation);

        return mapAnnotation;

    },

    updateAnnotation: function (mapAnnotation, title, subtitle, latitude, longitude, isLocation) {

        if (mapAnnotation) {
            map.mapView.removeAnnotation(mapAnnotation);
            mapAnnotation = map.createAnnotation(title, subtitle, latitude, longitude, isLocation);
            map.mapView.addAnnotation(mapAnnotation);
            map.mapView.selectAnnotation(mapAnnotation);
        }

    },

    addAnnotation: function (mapAnnotation) {

        map.mapView.addAnnotation(mapAnnotation);

    },

    removeAnnotation: function (mapAnnotation) {

        map.mapView.removeAnnotation(mapAnnotation);

    },

    selectAnnotation: function (mapAnnotation) {

        map.mapView.selectAnnotation(mapAnnotation);

    },

    createRoute: function (name, points) {

        var route = {
            name: name, points: points, color: "#7c74d4", width: 4
        };
        map.mapView.addRoute(route);
        setTimeout(function () { map.mapView.regionFit = true; }, 700);

    },

    getLocation: function() {

        Ti.Geolocation.preferredProvider = Ti.Geolocation.PROVIDER_GPS;
        Ti.Geolocation.purpose = "testing";
        Ti.Geolocation.accuracy = Ti.Geolocation.ACCURACY_BEST;
        Ti.Geolocation.distanceFilter = 10;

        if(!Ti.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled) {
            //alert('Your device has GPS turned off. Please turn it on.');
            return;
        }

        function updatePosition(e) {
            if(!e.success || e.error) {
                info("Unable to get your location - " + e.error);
                return;
            }
            info(JSON.stringify(e.coords));
            map.latitude = e.coords.latitude;
            map.longitude = e.coords.longitude;
            Ti.Geolocation.removeEventListener('location', updatePosition);
        };

        Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(updatePosition);    
        Ti.Geolocation.addEventListener('location', updatePosition);

    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a timeout to make sure the `e.coords` is set before you use it, it has been suggested as a temporary fix?

```
setTimeout(function() {
    return e.coords
}, 1000);
```

Comment: It _did_ take care of the error, but I'm still a getting lat/long of `undefined`. Not sure why. Maybe it's returning the response before the timeout fires?